# Observing click of ajax code checks elements in order

Tags: javascript, ajax, prototypejs

I have a problem where I need the document observe click function (or something similar) to get elements in order from child out.  The reason being is I want to have e.stopPropagation() on the child element, but the parent calls anyways because it is first in line.

For example:

```
   <script type="text/javascript"> 
    document.observe('click', function(e, el) {  
        if (el = e.findElement('.parent a')) { 
            e.stopPropagation();
        }
        if (el = e.findElement('.parent')){ 
            alert('parent');
        }
    });
    </script> 
    <div class="parent">
        <a href="test.html" target="_blank">Child Click Function</a>
        Parent Click Function
    </div>
```

In this example, parent gets found first, so the alert gets called.  the reason I have to to do it this way rather than the element.observer is that its Ajax generated content and Prototype doesn't appear to have a live() function like jQuery.

Does anyone have a work around for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prototype definitely does have a `.live()` equivalent and it is called [`Event.on()`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Event/on/). It also works as an instance method, [`Element#on()`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Element/prototype/on/).

```
document.on('click', '.parent', function(event, element) {
    if (!event.findElement('.parent a')) {
        alert('parent');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks.  While this works in my example, Ajax generated content it doesn't work.  You pointed me to the solution though.  I used my example with your conditional if (!e.findElement('.parent a')) {

Comment: I'm surprised that AJAX breaks it, `.on()` was created to get around the problem of dynamic content. I'm glad you found your answer though.

Answer (score 0):

You're observing on "document", the currentTarget of your event e is document.

'.parent a' and '.parent' exists in your document, so el.findElement('.parent a') and e.findElement('.parent') will always return an element.

.parent is not found first in your script, but you dont stop the process ( or use an if/else statement )  when you enter in your first if. So the process continue and the script find the .parent element in document.

Can you explain what you're trying to do ? Why do you want the event to stop bubbling ?

btw :
1) el is undefined in your script.
2) you use "=" and not "==" in your script when you're using findElement();

Comment: I am observing document clicks, which means that it only gets triggered when clicked.  I understand that both will be targeted, but wanted to stop the other.  From clockworkgeek's post, I realized I could just check to see if .parent a existed before doing .parents functions.  1) el is not undefined, it returns the correct element.  2) That is intentional to use the single "=", which works as expected.